# Static Method that takes integer array as parmeter and Return string

Tags: java, arrays, static-methods

I want to create a static method **Static String displayArray (int [] array)** that takes an integer array as parameter, uses a loop to create and return a new String that represents the contents of the array surrounded by braces and separated by commas.
For example,

```
int [] myArray = { 12,9,10,25};
String str = displayArray(myArray);
System.out.println (str);   // should display {12,9,10,25}
```

My solution:

```
public static String displayArray (int [] array) {
    for (int i=0; i< array.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(array[i]);
    }
    return null;
}
```

But it gives output as follows:

```
12
9
10
25
null
```

Comment: because of `returns null;`

Comment: Your loop uses `System.out.println` - it doesn't do anything to create a new string. Hint: use `StringBuilder` and `append`, then call `toString` at the end...

Comment: Just use [`Arrays.toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString-int:A-) and don't reinvent the wheel. Also, please format your code - it is currently barely legible.

Comment: I shouldn't use any additional package or utility

Comment: You should add that piece to your question right away.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
public static String displayArray (int [] array) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i=0; i< array.length; i++) {
        sb.append(array[i]);
        if(i!=array.length-1)
            sb.append(",");
    }
    return "{"+sb.toString()+"}";
}
```

Comment: Why creating extra String in `return "{"+sb.toString()+"}";`, when you can initialize the `StringBuilder` with `StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("{");`

Answer (score 1):

You need to build a String object to return.  Right now you are returning null, which is literally nothing.

I'd suggest using a StringBuilder, it's a little faster than concatenating Strings directly.  So before your loop you'll want to define a StringBuilder object and add the opening brace:

```
StringBuilder returnString = new StringBuilder();
returnString.append("{");
```

Then within your loop, you can concatenate each number:

```
returnString.append(Integer.toString(array[i]);
```

After that you'll want to make a check to see if you have the last element, if not, append a comma.

Finally append the closing brace, and instead of return null use:

```
return returnString.toString();
```

Comment: Code will still not have `,` separating the values and ending braces as well!

Comment: "After that you'll want to make a check to see if you have the last element, if not, append a comma." - I didn't want to write all the code for the OP.

Answer (score 1):

You might need this:

```
public static String displayArray(int[] array) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("{");
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            builder.append((array[i])).append(",");
        }
        return builder.substring(0, builder.length() - 1).concat("}");
    }
```

Comment: No condition in cycle, much faster +1

Answer (score 0):

Do this instead:

```
    public static String displayArray (int [] array) {

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i=0; i< array.length; i++) {

                sb.append(array[i]+",");
            }
String result=sb.toString()+",";
       result=result.replace(",,","");

    return "{"+result+"}";
    }
```

Comment: Missing commas and brackets

Comment: its give output like this : 2901415, I want it to be {12,9,10,25}

Comment: try this now, you can use the replace to get rid of last comma(s)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, exactly it is giving you the right output. 
To get your desired output you can modify your display array function as follow:

```
   public static String displayArray (int [] array) {
       String str = "";
       for (int i=0; i< array.length; i++) {
            str += array[i]+",";
       }
       returns str;
  }
```

Comment: There will be comma at the end of string, braces missing, and apending directly to string is not recommended because it is very slow operation

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers display the output like you wanted it.

```
public static String displayArray (int [] array) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("{");   
        for (int i=0; i< array.length; i++) {
            sb.append(array[i]);
            if(i != array.length-1)
              sb.append(",");
        }
    sb.append("}"); 
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: It's still have one extra `,`

Comment: @Arpit is that better?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String displayArray( int[] array )
{
    return "{" + Arrays.toString( array ).replace("[", "").replace("]", "")  + "}";
}
```

Going off of @BorisTheSpider idea and because I find this easier than `Stringbuilder`, here is your method to return the string `{ val1, val2, val3 }`.

Basically, print out your braces manually and replace the brackets with `""`.